# Adding states to Edit text element default is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a fragment with an image in the background I want to make the border of edittext change colors when it's pressed and when it is not but It's not working I tried deleting the backgroung image and i got the same result here is my code
rounded_edittext:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focused"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unfocused"
        /> <!-- defualt -->
</selector>
```

unfocused:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</selector>
```

focused:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#fff" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

and i added it to edittext here:

```
 android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
```

how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead of android:state_pressed use android:state_focused.

```
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/unfocused"
        /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focused"
        />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was here since I was using selector instead of shape :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000" />
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
    </selector>
```